# EVENT ID 7003 Microsoft Office 12 Sessions

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2007, active-directory

Microsoft Word 2007 crashed 2seconds after being launched. This happens only for the users from Active Directory. If I open the Word Document with administrator user, it works.

The Event Viewer returns Event ID 7003. I looked everywhere, but nothing.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. I'm using ESET ENDPOINT ANTIVIRUS and I had to disable the HIPS protection. everything is working just fine now.